# But does the Fermat Factorization algorithm work?

Tags: python, primes, factorization

I was testing the basic version of the Fermat Factorization method, so I'm not using any improvement whatsoever. The code I wrote in Python works as fast as expected for those numbers obtained by relatively close primes.

```
import math

N = int(input("Insert a large number: "))

def fermat_factorization(N: int) -> list[int]:
    if N % 2 == 0:
        return [2, N // 2]

    a = math.isqrt(N) + 1
    b_square = a**2 - N

    while not math.sqrt(b_square).is_integer():
        a += 1
        b_square = a**2 - N

    b = math.isqrt(b_square)
    return [a+b, a-b]

factors = fermat_factorization(N)
print(f"\nThe factor of {N} are {factors}")
```

However, upon checking for some large Mersenne primes (e.g. 2147483647), and playing with some more from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_known_prime_number), the output missed the marked completely (2147483647 gets factorized into 268435456*8). Is there some error in the code or should I expect the algorithm to fail for large primes?

Comment: `math.sqrt` uses imprecise floating-point math; you should check if `math.isqrt(b_square)**2 == b_square`, for example. Not immediately sure if that’s the only issue, though.

Comment: `float.is_integer()` is simply not as precise as you're hoping.  Past a certain magnitude, *all* floats are detected as integers, simply because all of the significant digits that they're capable of representing are to the left of the decimal point.

Comment: another problem is `a = math.isqrt(N) + 1` is not equivalent to `math.ceil(math.sqrt(N))` which is what Fermat factorization needs to initialize `a`.  Use `a = math.isqrt(N)` then `if a**2 != N: a += 1`.  Perfect squares have a bug otherwise, e.g. `25` returns `(25, 1)` instead of `(5, 5)`.

Comment: Thank you for your bits of advice. Despite having implemented what you said, and even using gmpy2 library instead of math, I find that the algorithm still factorizes 2147483647 incorrectly

Comment: @lanzik03: Can you show what you implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`math.sqrt` uses floating-point math, which isn’t precise enough for the size of integers you’re working with. You can discover this by doing some debugging:

```
while not math.sqrt(b_square).is_integer():
    a += 1
    b_square = a**2 - N

print(f"Done because {b_square} is a perfect square")
```

> Done because 18014397435740177 is a perfect square

```
>>> import math
>>> x = math.sqrt(18014397435740177)
>>> x
134217724.0
>>> int(x)**2
18014397435740176
>>> 18014397435740177.0 == 18014397435740176.0
True
```

Using integer math (with the fix @MarkTolonen suggested for the square `N` issue) will work:

```
def fermat_factorization(N: int) -> list[int]:
    if N % 2 == 0:
        return [2, N // 2]

    a = math.isqrt(N)
    if a**2 != N:
        a += 1

    b_square = a**2 - N

    while math.isqrt(b_square)**2 != b_square:
        a += 1
        b_square = a**2 - N

    b = math.isqrt(b_square)
    return [a+b, a-b]
```

> The factor of 2147483647 are [2147483647, 1]